# php count xml elements

Tags: php, xml

Hi what is the best way to count the number of elements in a XML file? In my case I want to count the number of XML tags with the name "OfferName" within the tag "OfferNameList".

The XML below is contained in a php variable $offers

```
$offers = '<OfferNameList>
  <OfferName>...</OfferName>
  <OfferName>...</OfferName>
  <OfferName>...</OfferName>
  ...
</OfferNameList>';
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With [`DOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you can either use

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('OfferName')->length;
```

to count ***all OfferName elements only***. [`length` is an attribute of `DOMNodeList`.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)

To count ***all OfferName elements within an OfferNameList***, you can use [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php)

```
$xpath->evaluate('count(//OfferNameList/OfferName');
```

Note that *within* is somewhat inaccurate here as the XPath query will only consider direct children. Please adjust your question if you need OfferName elements anywhere below a OfferNameList element.

Also note that `//` will query anywhere in the document, which might be less efficient for large documents. If you know OfferNameList elements occur at a certain position in your XML only, use a direct path.

---

**Full working example** ([run on codepad](http://codepad.org/U9hdW4oc)):

```
$xml = <<< XML
<root>
    <NotOfferNameList>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
    </NotOfferNameList>
    <OfferNameList>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
      <OfferName>...</OfferName>
    </OfferNameList>;
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// count all OfferName elements
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('OfferName')->length, PHP_EOL; // 6

// count all OfferNameList/OfferName elements
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xp->evaluate('count(//OfferNameList/OfferName)'); // 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! Please could you post this in your question so future readers can see this in case the above link goes dead.

Comment: Thank you! Well answered and very much appreciated!

Comment: I am still seeking an question answer as my question is closed and days duplicated as this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234985/php-xml-count-numbers/ I want to count the "string" from array, but just element. could you please help. thanks

Answer (score 4):

eighter you use simplexml: http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.count.php

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOF
<OfferNameList>
 <OfferName>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </OfferName>
 <OfferName>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </OfferName>
</OfferNameList>
EOF;

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
printf("%d offers.\n", $elem->OfferNameList->count() );

?>
```

or do it with DOM

```
 $domobj->getElementsByTagName('OfferName')->length;
```

Comment: This assumes OfferNameList only has OfferName children and is exactly why I am not using SimpleXml. It forces you to make assumptions about the markup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP function [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr-count.php)

```
<?php
  $tag_count = substr_count($offers, "<OfferName>");
?>
```

You might need to extract the content of the  tags by using a regular expression first.

If you are the author of the XML file, you could also simply embed the count as an attribute of the OfferNameList tag, such as ....

Finally, if you need to parse the XML file, I would strongly suggest to get a proper XML parser (DOM Parser will count the inner tags for you, assuming your XML is not too big) but you will also be able to do it with a SAX parser implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to solution given by @Gordon  (which works perfectly fine for the question asked), its not mentioned and for people who it is not very obvious to:
It is possible to use `evaluate` if you want to count  `OfferName` from some XML like:
`

```
<OfferNameList>
 <OfferName>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </OfferName>
 <OfferName>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </OfferName>
</OfferNameList>

<OfferNameList>
 <OfferName>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </OfferName>
</OfferNameList>
```

One can use

`echo $xp->evaluate('count(//OfferNameList[1]/OfferName)');` 
to count it from **FIRST** OfferNameList and

`echo $xp->evaluate('count(//OfferNameList[2]/OfferName)');` to count it from **SECOND**.

P.S.:

I'm just posting this answer here because I wanted to achieve something like what I just showed and I found this post on google'ing!

Seondly, we use 1 and 2 to access the **FIRST** and **SECOND** lists and **NOT** 0 and 1. Newbies like me might not know this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dom->count()` for PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php)