# How to count XML elements

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php count xml elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

I have an XML file that contains video titles

```
<videolist>
<video>
<title>Title1</title>
</video>

<video>
<title>Title2</title>
</video>
</videolist>
```

How to count the number of video elements? I usually use simpleXML to read XML files. From the above example, there are a couple of video elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
$s = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
echo count($s -> video);
```

Comment: Do I really need to use the dom node? How about if I use simplexml_load_file("xml") for opening xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of count()'ing the SimpleXML object's 'video' property.

I've also included a function to convert the simpleXML object to an array which you can count() as well.

```
<?php

$xml = '
<videolist>
<video>
<title>Title1</title>
</video>

<video>
<title>Title2</title>
</video>
</videolist>
';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

print count($sxe->video)."\n";

$array = simpleXMLToArray($sxe);

print count($array['video'])."\n";

function simpleXMLToArray($xml,
                        $flattenValues=true,
                        $flattenAttributes = true,
                        $flattenChildren=true,
                        $valueKey='@value',
                        $attributesKey='@attributes',
                        $childrenKey='@children'){

                $return = array();
                if(!($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement)){return $return;}
                $name = $xml->getName();
                $_value = trim((string)$xml);
                if(strlen($_value)==0){$_value = null;};

                if($_value!==null){
                        if(!$flattenValues){$return[$valueKey] = $_value;}
                        else{$return = $_value;}
                }

                $children = array();
                $first = true;
                foreach($xml->children() as $elementName => $child){
                        $value = simpleXMLToArray($child, $flattenValues, $flattenAttributes, $flattenChildren, $valueKey, $attributesKey, $childrenKey);
                        if(isset($children[$elementName])){
                                if($first){
                                        $temp = $children[$elementName];
                                        unset($children[$elementName]);
                                        $children[$elementName][] = $temp;
                                        $first=false;
                                }
                                $children[$elementName][] = $value;
                        }
                        else{
                                $children[$elementName] = $value;
                        }
                }
                if(count($children)>0){
                        if(!$flattenChildren){$return[$childrenKey] = $children;}
                        else{$return = array_merge($return,$children);}
                }

                $attributes = array();
                foreach($xml->attributes() as $name=>$value){
                        $attributes[$name] = trim($value);
                }
                if(count($attributes)>0){
                        if(!$flattenAttributes){$return[$attributesKey] = $attributes;}
                        else{$return = array_merge($return, $attributes);}
                }

                return $return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a simple XSLT script that just outputs some text.
You can view the various functions that [PHP provides for XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)

A simple script would kind of look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(/videolist/video)" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To load this, your script could look like this:

```
<?php

 $yourXMLData = '<videolist>...</videolist>';
 $XSLTScript = '<xsl:stylesheet ... ';

 // Load the XML source
 $xml = new DOMDocument;
 $xml->load($yourXMLData);

 $xsl = new DOMDocument;
 $xsl->load($XSLTScript);

 // Configure the transformer
 $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
 $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

 echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

?>
```