# PHP - count li elements inside ul

Tags: php, html, count, html-lists

i'm searching for a way to count dynamic li elements inside an ul in php (not js).

For example:

```
<ul>

  <li> lorem </li>

  <li> ipsum </li>

  <li> dolor </li>

  <li> sit </li>

</ul>
```

would return me the number **4**.
(am i too stupid to use proper code here?)

Is there some way to accomplish that in php?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The markup is generated by a cms system, the count should be placed before the list, inside the template file.

Comment: *"am i too stupid to use proper code here?"* - You surely did a good job at ignoring the help that the editor tried to slap in your face. ;)

Comment: Are you generating this HTML yourself? Does it come from some external source?

Comment: Are you using PHP to generate this html table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php count xml elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Comment: Tomalak, yeah i didnt see that, thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 12):

You can do a very simple [Substring Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) for `<li>` (or `-li-`) on that string and it would return the number of items.

---

Edit:

```
$count = substr_count($html,'<li>'); //where $html holds your piece of HTML.
```

Comment: As it's very simple I would even suggest count both. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you show me a example? I'm not shure how to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks again! I need to identify the ul using it's tag ID ('portfolio') how would i do that?

Comment: you should have written that in your question from the start. Use the other solutions suggested and do your homework.

Comment: oh, what a nice person you are, tom. I'm a designer, not a developer... i came here to get help, and not some stupid answers

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this HTML is not output by you (otherwise it should be trivial to count the number of elements), you could use PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $ul) {

   $count = $ul->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;

   var_dump($count);

}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RcAc6G).

This code will count the number of `li` elements in each `ul` element. If you don't care about individual `ul` elements, just use `$dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length`.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer lies with [DOMDocument](http://il.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

For example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom -> loadHTML("<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>");
$li = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
foreach ($li as $li_c){
$i++;
}
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's DOM library, or look up Simple DOM Parser. It contain searches for HTML