# Count how many children are in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i know a few about php, so sorry for the question:

i have this file xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <alert>
   <status> </status>
   <nothing> </nothing>
   <info>
    <area>
    </area>
   </info>
   <info>
    <area>
    </area>
   </info>
   <info>
    <area>
    </area>
   </info>
  </alert>
```

i must do a for loop and inside a "foreach" for each 
The problem is that i'm not sure what is a way to know how many times i had to repeat a for loop. Because in this file xml (that is an example) i don't know how many are

Is good if:

```
$url = "pathfile";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$numvulcani = count($xml->alert->info); // is good ?

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numvulcani; $i++) {
 foreach ($xml->alert->info[$i] as $entry) {
  $area = $entry->area;
 }
}
```

is true ?

sorry for bad english

Comment: What are you triyng to achieve? Have you tried `foreach` loop?

Comment: i would like to know if count() in my example is good :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `foreach ($xml->alert->info[$i] as $entry)` with:

```
 foreach ($xml->alert->info[$i] as $j => $entry)
```

The current item index will be `$j`

Comment: Yes, `count()` is fine

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ***SimpleXMLElement::count*** function for this — It counts the children of an element.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOF
<people>
 <person name="Person 1">
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </person>
 <person name="Person 2">
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </person>
</people>
EOF;

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($elem as $person) {
    printf("%s has got %d children.\n", $person['name'], $person->count());
}
?>
```

The output will be as follows :

> Person 1 has got 3 children. 
>   Person 2 has got 5 children.

Also take a look at this link : [xml count using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You're perhaps overcomplicating this a bit as it's new to you.

First of all, you don't need to reference the *alert* root element like `$xml->alert` because the **SimpleXMLElement** named by the variable `$xml` represents that document element *already*.

And second, you don't need to count here, you can just `foreach` directly:

```
foreach ($xml->info as $info) {
    echo ' * ', $info->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

This iterates over those three *info* elements that are children of the *alert* element.

I recommend the [*Basic SimpleXML usage* guide in the PHP manual](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) for a good start with SimpleXML.