# Displaying how many start and end tags are in an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around PHP. I haven't had any luck finding these answers online. I've done the same thing with C, but with C it's much easier because you can use pointers.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in a file from the command line, read that file, and search for any '<' , '>', and closing tags that are inside the XML file, then print out to the terminal how many there are of each.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm completely stuck.

Comment: do you mean to count total items or all tags, including items + children and root tag? If you know how to do it, perhaps you can do it on C and just call it from php using shell_exec() ?

Comment: Have a look at XML tree parsers - though I don't know the exact name in PHP, there should be equivalents to libraries like Etree. You feed it the XML, and out comes a tree structure which you can then traverse and count. Some libraries even allow searching and listing tags by name.

Comment: what do u have so far? SOF is not a place to make people do ur homework 4 u. BTW u may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
int substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 [, int $length ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr-count.php