# Count PHP/XML getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have a script, that parses a RSS-Feed Url with PHP to make a ticker.

```
$xml=("http://www.herecomesthedomain.com/andyourrssfeed.rss");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ('< li >' . $item_title . '</ li >');
}
```

But the loop contains a fixed number (9).

Is it possible to count the
    `$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item')`

Variable a dynamic loop?

I tried different solutions, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php count xml elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Comment: `foreach ($x as $xx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the length of a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) using `$x->length`, but the tidiest way would probably be to use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($x as $item) {
    $item_title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo ('< li >' . $item_title . '</ li >');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i got it with your help:

```
$count = ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('title')->length)-2;
```

and the loop is called:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
```

I have to subtract 2 elements (1x for the channel title and i think one for the array starting number (is 0 instead of 1). Now it works.

The full code:

```
$xml=("http://www.herecomesthedomain.com/andyourrssfeed.rss");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)
->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

// Count the title-"<item>"-elements
$count= ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('title')->length)-2;

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=$anzahl; $i++) {
$item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)
->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)
->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo ("<li>" . $item_title . "</li>");
}
```