# How to count nodes of an xml file with php?

Tags: php, xml

I know that maybe is a duplicate but doesn't works....

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>EMSC - Last 2 Weeks earthquakes worldwide</name>
        <Folder>
            <name>2017 7 - 13</name>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>2017 7 - 12</name>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

i want count node `Folder`, i tied this

```
$pars_emsc= simplexml_load_file('/file');

$count_folder_emsc= $pars_emsc-> Document -> getElementsByTagName('Folder')->length;
```

but doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php count xml elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Comment: `simplexml` is a little too simple to easily do what you want to do. I would suggest looking at the answers in the question linked by @GrumpyCrouton, and use `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the simple XML parser as a DOM document. Quite simply `getElementsByTagName` doesn't exist in `SimpleXML`. Use this instead:

```
$pars_emsc = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );
$pars_emsc->load("/file");
$count_folder_emsc= $pars_emsc->getElementsByTagName("Document")[0]->getElementsByTagName('Folder')->length;

print_r($count_folder_emsc);
```

Alternatively just do:

```
$pars_emsc= simplexml_load_file("/file");
$count_folder_emsc= $pars_emsc-> Document -> Folder -> count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath expressions can count nodes, too.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('kml', 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(//kml:Folder)'));
```

Output:

```
float(2)
```

You XML uses a default namespace, so you have to register a prefix for it.